# Typescript - Sort strings descending

Tags: arrays, typescript

I'm trying to sort a `string[]` in **descending** way. So far what I have done is the code below:

```
let values = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"]; // example 

values.sort();
values.reverse();
```

It's working but I'm trying to figure out if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: A better way?  Better *how*?  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: `values.sort((a,b) => 0 - (a > b ? 1 : -1));`?

Comment: Like haim said, provide a comparison function (check out the array sort docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). You would do the sort and provide a comparison function, perhaps you could also take advantage of the string localCompare (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

Comment: @haim770 great!

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You need to create a comparison function and pass it as a parameter of sort function:

```
values.sort((one, two) => (one > two ? -1 : 1));
```

Comment: Does this hack consider the case in array of strings?

Comment: @Memmo I'm not sure what your asking. It will compare the character values one by one. Uppercase will sort ahead of lower case.

Comment: I understand. I'm looking for a way to sort them in the same way as the lowercase ones. So that there is no case difference.

Comment: Call uppercase() on both of them before the comparison.

Answer (score 77):

A more current answer is that you can utilize String.prototype.localCompare() to get a numeric comparison value

Simple example:

```
let values = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
values.sort((a, b) => b.localeCompare(a))
```

This also wont causes TypeScript warnings as the output of `localCompare` is a number

More info and additional function parameters can be seen here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare

Comment: this won't work with 
['9', '75', '72', '64', '61', '60', '6', '59', '57', '56', '54', '53', '52', '5', '47', '46', '44', '42', '41', '40', '4', '3', '26', '25', '22', '21', '20', '2', '19', '17', '16', '14', '13', '12']

Comment: @VirajSingh to sort numeric string values you will need to use `values.sort((a, b) => b.localeCompare(a, undefined, {numeric: true}))`

Comment: This is a more elegant solution than `a.toUpperCase() > b.toUpperCase() ? -1 : 1`, but be careful with very large datasets, `localeCompare` is about twice slower, even though it still is pretty quick.

Answer (score 14):

Use the following code to sorting the Array in ascending and descending order.

```
const ascending: any= values.sort((a,b) =>  (a > b ? 1 : -1));
const descending: any= values.sort((a,b) => (a > b ? -1 : 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

The most recent lib that I know

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-pipes

```
const numbers = [2, 1, 3];
 
const obj = [
  {id: 4, name: 'Dave', amount: 2},
  {id: 2, name: 'Michael', amount: 2},
  {id: 3, name: 'Dan', amount: 1},
  {id: 1, name: 'John', amount: 1}
];
 
const deepObj = [
  {id: 1, name: 'John', amount: 1337, deep: {prop: 4}},
  {id: 2, name: 'Michael', amount: 42, deep: {prop: 2}},
  {id: 3, name: 'Dan', amount: 1, deep: {prop: 1}},
  {id: 4, name: 'Dave', amount: 2, deep: {prop: 3}}
];

<!-- Returns array ordered by value -->
<p>{{ numbers | orderBy }}</p>  <!-- Output: [1, 2, 3] -->
<p>{{ numbers | orderBy: '-' }}</p>  <!-- Output: [3, 2, 1] -->
 
<!-- Returns array ordered by value of property -->
<p>{{ deepObj | orderBy: 'amount' }}</p>  
<!-- Output: [{id: 3, ...}, {id: 4, ...}, {id: 2, ...}, {id: 1, ...}] -->
<p>{{ deepObj | orderBy: '-amount' }}</p>  
<!-- Output: [{id: 1, ...}, {id: 2, ...}, {id: 4, ...}, {id: 3, ...}] -->
 
<!-- Returns array ordered by value of deep property -->
<p>{{ deepObj | orderBy: 'deep.prop' }}</p>  
<!-- Output: [{id: 3, ...}, {id: 2, ...}, {id: 4, ...}, {id: 1, ...}] -->
<p>{{ deepObj | orderBy: '-deep.prop' }}</p>  
<!-- Output: [{id: 1, ...}, {id: 4, ...}, {id: 2, ...}, {id: 3, ...}] -->
 
<!-- Returns array ordered by mutliple properties -->
<p>{{ obj | orderBy: ['amount', 'id'] }}</p>  
<!-- Output: [{id: 1, ...}, {id: 3, ...}, {id: 2, ...}, {id: 4, ...}] -->
```

**Must be like this programmatically**

```
@Component({
  // ..
  providers: [OrderByPipe]
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private orderByPipe: OrderByPipe){
     let values = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
     this.orderByPipe.transform(values, '-');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is normal reverse sorting

```
var nums:number[] = [1,2,3,4]
nums.sort((a,b)=> a < b ? 1:-1)
[ 4, 3, 2, 1 ]
```

If you have to do the sorting of custom objects, try this

```
class Student{
    name:String
    marks:Number
    constructor(name:string, marks:number) {
        this.name = name
        this.marks = marks
    }
}

var students:Array<Student> = [
    new Student("aseem",47),
    new Student("prem",97),
    new Student("john",100)

]

console.log(students.sort( (a,b)=> a.marks > b.marks ? -1:1 ))
```

would result in sorting by marks in reverse order

```
/usr/local/bin/node /Users/asee2278/git/mycode/JavaScriptLab/typeScript/concepts/sort.js
[
  Student { name: 'john', marks: 100 },
  Student { name: 'prem', marks: 97 },
  Student { name: 'aseem', marks: 47 }
]
```

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)).